# calling a servlet during a page load

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

when a user clicks on exit link in homepage.jsp:

I do a href and send the request to exit.jsp.

Now when the exit.jsp loads, I need to make a call to a servlet to expire the user's token.

The servlet call would not return anything, it just makes a database update and expires the token. The rest of exit.jsp should load as usual.

How do I make a call to this servlet when exit.jsp is loading?

I do not want to use `<a href={servlet url}>` as this means something needs to be clicked to make the servlet call. But in my case, servlet call should happen when exit.jsp loads. Nothing will be clicked.

Another option is to use `<img src ={servlet url}>`...but doesn't seem right.

Any other options ?

This is a legacy application. So, I would prefer to use Javascript

Answer (score 0):

Simply send the token clear request your servlet in your exit.jsp loading process. One of the ways of doing it is using jquery and ajax.

Comment: yes query is just a javascript wrapper, so use javascript if you want.

Comment: any tips/examples on how do to do it though ?...thanks

Comment: if you hit the search button with proper search strings. You may get better examples/source code that I can provide. My answer was to guide but not to spoon feed you. Good luck!